# Custom annotation doesn't work when imported as jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, aop

I'm developing a personal project in order to learn new things like:
* Spring Boot, Spring Data, Angular 4*, ecc..
You can find them here : [GitHub](https://github.com/StefanoPisano)

So I tried to create a custom annotation named *LogMe* which has to log some informations about the method where it is placed like *name of the method, parameters ecc..*

At first, I created it inside my personal project and it worked as I want.
Find it here: [Git Hub repo](https://github.com/StefanoPisano/expenses-app/tree/0.5) 
The annotation is in package *annotation* and it is used in the controller *UserController*

Next, I wanted to create a jar with that annotation in order to import it on my projects and to publish it on my GitHub profile.
So I take the two classes, moved to a new project and created a jar, I imported it with maven in the *expenses-app* project successfully (I didn' get any error) and used the annotation on the method of the controller but it seems that spring ignore it, it doesn't log anything and I can't understand where is the problem.

Do you have any idea? This is the repository with the annotation: [LogMe 
 repo](https://github.com/StefanoPisano/log-me)

Comment: 1. There is no LogMe annotation on the controller 2. How have you configured the component scanning, so that the interceptor is recognized as bean? If you don't want to add the package of the interceptor, you have to add a method with the `@Bean` annotation to one of your config classes, where you return an instance of your interceptor.

Comment: @dunni The method annotation is in userController. You have to select 'release 0.5'. I didn't know that! I'm going to try this

Comment: Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The relevant code for your problem should be part of your question, not hidden within some Github repositories.

Comment: @dunni thank you! It worked!!